# Was the typo in Paul Allen's busines card ever explained?

Tags: american-psycho

Inspired by my previous question... [Why would Patrick Bateman share a phone number with Paul Allen and Timothy Bryce?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45238/why-would-patrick-bateman-share-a-phone-number-with-paul-allen-and-timothy-bryce)

At this point it seems that most people have learned of the misspelled word, "Acquisitions," in Paul Allen's business card but was this ever explained / "retconned?"

[image]

Is there a chance this was intentional?

Comment: Bateman doesn't work in Mergers and acquisitions anyways.  He works in _murders and executions_  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the three cards have the same typo.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Aquistions is a very common mistake for Acquisitions, especially in the context of "Mergers and Acquisitions", see [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=aquisitions&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisuLmHvPXJAhUBXD4KHZepCJcQvgUIGygB&biw=1065&bih=688).

There has been no statement by the production crew about this. [The error wasn't even seen until around 2013](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/22/american-psycho-typo-business-cards_n_4143823.html).

So chuck it up to production error.